# JSON file / script preventing page from displaying.

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a JSON file that is approx 500 lines long.  The script that reads in the file is the first thing to happen when the page is loaded.  The script works perfectly.  It updates a drop down box automatically depending on a users choice.

A moment ago I added an additional 50 lines or so to the JSON file, maintained correct syntax etc etc.  When I reloaded the page there was nothing but a white screen, no error logs etc.  I removed what I had added to the JSON and received the same white screen, I'd also reloaded the page after clearing cache and on different browsers, same thing.

I then commented out the script that calls the JSON, reloaded and voila, it's fine.  I un-comment the script again so it is as it was and magic, it now works.

Can anyone explain what could be happening and how I might solve it please?  I can't force it to happen again but that doesn't mean it won't.

Many thanks.

Simplified sample of JSON:

```
"angle" : [

    {
        "value":"degree",
        "name":"Degree (deg)"
    },
    {
        "value":"grad",
        "name":"Grad (grad)"
    }]
```

The script that calls it:

```
 <script>
    $.getJSON('JSON/conversionJSON.json', function(data){

        $.each(data, function (key, conversions) {
            console.log(key + ":" + conversions);

            $.each(conversions, function (index, conversion) {
                console.log("<li>Name: " + conversion.name + " :Value: " + conversion.value + "</li>");

                if(key == "<?php echo $conversionType ?>"){

                    $("#to").append('<option class="'+key+'" id="'+conversion.value+'" value="'+conversion.value+'">'+conversion.name+'</option>');

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: console error? missing `;` maybe? provide a less simplified code. You could use jsfiddle.net with jslint to check syntax errors and more

Comment: Most likely invalid JSON - check here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I'd already validated the JSON - that site is amazing, it was fine.  I literally commented the script, refreshed, uncommented it again and it working.  Nothing was changed, no missing semi colons etc etc.